# Why does pd.Timedelta modulo int work, but not plus int?

Tags: python, pandas

One can use modulo on Pandas Timedeltas with any number, but addition results in an unsupported error. The following example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_timedelta(7, "s") % 3
pd.to_timedelta(7, "s") + 3
```

results in

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-edd04d4a1971> in <module>
      3 pd.to_timedelta(7, "s") % 3
      4 
----> 5 pd.to_timedelta(7, "s") + 3

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'int'
```

Is there a deeper reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [code for the Timedelta object](http://pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta), we can see that the `__mod__` function just calls the `__divmod__` function, and returns the second value; which looks like the following:

```
def __divmod__(self, other):
    # Naive implementation, room for optimization
    div = self // other
    return div, self - div * other
```

So `%` will work with anything that can divide a `Timedelta` object - we can see what `__floordiv__` accepts from the implementation in the same link.

Comment: Thanks for digging that out. If I interpret that correctly, Pandas assumes the `int` to be in ns (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx#L1433). This does not feel consistent to the error in addition imo ...

Comment: Exactly - if you look in the `__add__` method, it just tries to add using a lambda, without converting the int to a `datetime` object. Maybe open an issue on github - even if it's rejected, you might be able to get some clarity on why this behaviour is.

Comment: There are some issues and PRs around this open (and closed), the reason seems to be that int // timedelta somehow made it into the docs as way to compute the Linux epoch, so cleaning that behavior up breaks stuff. At least for some similar operations they raise now warnings (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21036).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it only if you show which part of datetime you want to use,
for example:

```
time=pd.to_timedelta(7, "s")
print(time)
0 days 00:00:07
print(time.seconds%3)
1
```

You cannot divide using different types